# Mootools 1.3.1: chain animations and animate 2 elements synchronisly

Tags: javascript, animation, mootools, mootools-fx

I want to animate the `div#w_xxx` and the `div#w_xxx img` at the same time.

They should get bigger and after this they should get to their old width and height.

The problem is, mootools plays all animations at the same time so I cant see the animation and I tried some `.chain`function from mootools but I didnt get it working.

My code looks like this:

```
$("w_"+current_item+"").set('morph', {
            duration: 1000,
            transition: Fx.Transitions.Bounce.easeOut
        });
        $("w_"+current_item+"").morph({
                    'opacity': '1',
                    'width': 366,
                    'height': 240,
                    'z-index': '100'
        });

        $$("div#w_"+current_item+" img").set('morph', {
            duration: 1000,
            transition: Fx.Transitions.Bounce.easeOut
        });
        $$("div#w_"+current_item+" img").morph({
                    'opacity': '1',
                    'width': 366,
                    'height': 240,
                    'z-index': '100'
        });

        $("w_"+current_item+"").set('morph', {
            duration: 1000,
            transition: Fx.Transitions.Bounce.easeOut
        });
        $("w_"+current_item+"").morph({
                    'opacity': '1',
                    'width': 183,
                    'height': 120,
                    'z-index': '100'
        });

        $$("div#w_"+current_item+" img").set('morph', {
            duration: 1000,
            transition: Fx.Transitions.Bounce.easeOut
        });
        $$("div#w_"+current_item+" img").morph({
                    'opacity': '1',
                    'width': 183,
                    'height': 120,
                    'z-index': '100'
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at `Fx.Elements` from MooTools-more: http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Elements, which has been designed to run multiple animations on a unified timer.

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/tC4V4/

```
// mock your current_item... 
var current_item = 1;

var w = document.id("w_" + current_item);
new Fx.Elements($$(w, w.getElement("img")), {
    onComplete: function() {
        console.log("done");
    },
    duration: 4000,
    transition: Fx.Transitions.Bounce.easeOut,
    link: "chain"
}).start({
    0: {
        'opacity': '1',
        'width': 366,
        'height': 240,
        'z-index': '100'
    },
    1: {
        'opacity': '1',
        'width': 183,
        'height': 120,
        'z-index': '100'

    }   
}).start({
    0: {
        opacity: 0
    }  

});
```

By the same token, it supports link: chain so you can chain things or wait etc.

Comment: thanks =) its so frustrating with the spare documentation of mootools if you worked so many years with jquery

Comment: well it seems the div and the image are not resizing to their old values. also my structure is like <div id="w_100"><img src=""></div>

Comment: read the old values first, store them into an object and pass them back :). BTW, why not use scale transforms if available - they will be smoother. use mootools if not.

Comment: used now mootools and had to change some values  after the 1: { the values had to be 366 and 240 and not 183 and 120  because i wanted to transform both of the elements to these sizes

Comment: sure, mine was just an example :)